# Php Mysql help. Combine 2 mysql tables and provide a report

Tags: php, mysql

Please help:

I have 2 tables. Examples:

1. Customers (contains id, name, email etc.)
2. Orders (contains orderid, ownerid(=Customers.id), paymentstatus etc.)

I want to run a query that can display all customer names from Customers Table and also show how many total, unpaid and paid orders this customer has using the Orders table.

Example:

```
----------------------------
| Customer | Paid | Unpaid | TotalOrders 
----------------------------
|  cus_a   | 2000 |  5000  | 7000
|  cus_b   | 1680 |  4880  | xxxx
|  cus_b   | 5780 |  3720  | xxxx
----------------------------
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    c.name,
    ifnull(sum(case when paymentstatus = 'Paid' then amount end), 0) Paid,
    ifnull(sum(case when paymentstatus != 'Paid' then amount end), 0) Unpaid,
    ifnull(sum(o.amount),0) as TotalOrders
from customer c
left join orders o on o.ownerid=c.id
group by c.id, c.name
```

If you don't have an amount column that you are summing, just use COUNT instead

```
select
    c.name,
    count(case when paymentstatus = 'Paid' then amount end) Paid,
    count(case when paymentstatus != 'Paid' then amount end) Unpaid,
    count(o.ownerid) as TotalOrders
from customer c
left join orders o on o.ownerid=c.id
group by c.id, c.name
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR TRYING TO HELP ME OUT but when I run the query in the first answer, I get "Unknown column paid in fieldlist" and when I run the query in the second answer, I get "Unknown column amount in fieldlist". I have one column PAYMENTSTATUS that contains entries paid and unpaid. I don't have any column with the names Paid or Unpaid. Also I am not totaling the amounts. I just want to count total orders (total records in PATMENTSTATUS Field), unpaid orders (in PATMENTSTATUS Field) and paid orders (in PATMENTSTATUS Field). Thanks again for any help..

Comment: Thanks Richard. Your code helped me fully. I just modified it a bit and it is working 100% as expected by me. Here is the modified code: 
select
    c.name,
    count(case when paymentstatus = 'Paid' then paymentstatus end) tPaid,
    count(case when paymentstatus != 'Paid' then paymentstatus end) tUnpaid,
    count(o.ownerid) as TotalOrders 
from imgup_users c 
left join orders o on o.ownerid=c.id
group by c.id, c.name
I am really thankful to you and all who tried to help me. I really appreciate it. You and stackoverflow are both great!!! THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: Hi Richard, your query helped me a lot but now I have a new scenario so can you please help. The above query use to find out total unpaid orders for all users with unique IDs but I have added some sub accounts so I now need to include billing/unpaid orders of sub accounts with main account. To do this I have added a column in main account which contains all IDs of sub accounts so that I can find all due orders like this SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM TABLE WHERE PAYMENTSTATUS='UNPAID' AND IDS in (CONCATE('ID', ',' , LINKEDSUBACCOUNTS)). HOPE THIS MAKES SENSE?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a left outer join.

```
SELECT 
     c.*,
     count(o.paid) as paid,
     count(o.unpaid) as unpaid
FROM 
     customers c
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Order
        ON c.id = o.ownerid
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR TRYING TO HELP ME OUT but when I run the query in the first answer, I get "Unknown column paid in fieldlist" and when I run the query in the second answer, I get "Unknown column amount in fieldlist". I have one column PAYMENTSTATUS that contains entries paid and unpaid. I don't have any column with the names Paid or Unpaid. Also I am not totaling the amounts. I just want to count total orders (total records in PATMENTSTATUS Field), unpaid orders (in PATMENTSTATUS Field) and paid orders (in PATMENTSTATUS Field). Thanks again for any help...